# How to write the elements of a list into file by lines?

Tags: python-2.7

How to write the elements of a list into file by lines?
For example, I have a list ['apple','orange','peach']
I want the write the the list into the file as below:

apple
orange
peach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
f = open('workfile', 'w')
for l in list:
       f.write(l)
       f.write("\n")
f.close()
```